# Sync sql database to azure sql database

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have a sql database in my local network and I want synchronize it with azure sql server once per day...please explain a method to do...

Comment: This site is for programming questions. DB configuration is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want customized sync (once per day),you will need to use customized solution like  writing an app which compares and inserts the data..

If you want continuous sync,you have a solution ..

[Transactional Replication to Azure SQL DB now in public preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/)

This new capacity of Transactional Replication is available starting with the following versions\updates of SQL Server:

Community Technology Preview (CTP) 3.0 of SQL Server 2016
SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 Cumulative Update 3
SQL Server 2014 RTM Cumulative Update 10
SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2 Cumulative Update 8

This enables two main scenarios:
Migrate your data to Azure SQL DB with no downtime.
Bridge SQL Server on-premises/on VMs to Azure SQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) to setup the sync. you can set sync interval for 1 days

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)